# What would cause `docker build` to behave differently when ran on GitHub repository address vs. a local instance of that repository?

Tags: docker, github

How do I build this repository locally from a Dockerfile?

When I run this:

```
docker build https://github.com/mapillary/OpenSfM.git
```

I get the desired result:

```
Successfully built f4e8d06f3d58
```

However:

When I run this:

```
git clone https://github.com/mapillary/OpenSfM.git
docker build OpenSfM
```

I get that unexpected error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:53 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    /source/OpenSfM/opensfm/src/third_party/pybind11

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.


CMake Error at bundle/CMakeLists.txt:49 (pybind11_add_module):
  Unknown CMake command "pybind11_add_module".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/source/OpenSfM/cmake_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/source/OpenSfM/cmake_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Configuring for python 3.8...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 46, in <module>
    configure_c_extension()
  File "setup.py", line 37, in configure_c_extension
    subprocess.check_call(cmake_command, cwd="cmake_build")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '../opensfm/src', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I am new to Docker and my intuition says it should behave the same. It does not. Why? And how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This repository uses submodules, meaning they included other repos in some folders, which aren't cloned by default. (So you'll end up with some missing files) You can clone recursively with the command:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/mapillary/OpenSfM.git
```

Docker build clones the repos recursively, that's why the build was successful there.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. :) I am grateful!

Comment: Glad I could help!